# How do I listen for tab changes in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using `Fragment` class and `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` to implement swipe tabs.

I have 3 java class:

(OneFragment extends Fragment, TwoFragment extends Fragment, ThreeFragment extends Fragment and MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity)

Also I have 4 different xml files for all these class. In fact, I designed my code according to [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Now I want to listen when user switch between tabs. For example When the user goes 1st tab to 2nd tab, I want this to execute:

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You are exit from 1st tab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
```

Or when the user goes to 1st or 3rd tab from 2, this should be executed:

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You are exit from 2nd tab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
```

It is interesting that I couldn't any answer for `TabLayout`, although there are tens of answers for `Tabhost`.

How can I design my code to understand "which tab is changing, What is previous tab?" in `TabLayout` ?

**Note:** I used, tried to override `onDestroyView()`, `onDestroy()` and `onHiddenChanged()` but I couldn't  solve my problem. Only `onDestroy()` worked but it is working when the user exits the application as well.

Comment: Well formed question. Nice to see someone putting in effort in asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to implement the `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` interface for that.

Use `addOnTabSelectedListener` and `removeOnTabSelectedListener` methods to do so. Note that `setOnTabSelectedListener` is now deprecated.

Comment: Also check the developer docs of [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) for the Java Docs and maybe some useful examples. As a rule of thumb, do check the http://developer.android.com when stuck in similar problems. :)

Comment: My native language is not English so I have a problem with English although I made effort to develop my English. :) Therefore I can not understand anything from developer.android.com. They are too formal

Comment: @GürkanÇatak I don't understand what you mean by "formal". Formal terms can be easily translated, slangs will make it difficult. ;)

Comment: @GürkanÇatak if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.